# Creating Mutually Exclusive Check Box List in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, checkboxlist, mutual-exclusion

I have a check box list which is binded from code behind.
There can be at time one check box, two or more.
I want to add mutual exclusion property on the same. Is there a way to do so.
All the articles I am searching are creating static check box list.
Tried adding Ajax extender but no help.

Below is my code so far:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="LifeAccChk" runat="server" CssClass="itemRightAlign" />
 <asp:MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender ID="MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender1" runat="server" Key="Life" TargetControlID="LifeAccChk">
</asp:MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender>
```

Comment: A "mutually exclusive checkbox" is a radiobutton

Comment: I need a checkbox only, as radiobutton once checked cannot be unchecked easily, Any clue with checkbox?

Comment: why not just have a "none" option? the advantage of a radio button is the user will know implicitly that it is mutually exclusive. This isn't true with checkboxes. If you have a round hole use a round peg, not a square one.